# MongoDB: Sorting, subtracting dates and counting

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm a begginer in MongoDB and I'm practising the aggregation method. I'm my example, I would like to get the wine which has been produced in the last 5 years (5 years back from the newest wine), then I would like to count how many wines have been produced in that period of time (the database gives us the year of the wines, in an integer)

I believe that first, I have to sort the wines by year, then I should get the year of the newest wine, and sustract five years, using that period of time to count the wines. But I don't know how to write all of that using the aggregation code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use various aggregation pipeline stages to transform your data.

MongoDB’s [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) is modeled on the concept of data processing pipelines. Documents enter a multi-stage pipeline that transforms the documents into an aggregated result.

As you have mentioned,

1. First you have to get the year of the newest wine.

I have used [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to group the data, and [$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) is used to get `newestWineYear` and entire documents($$ROOT) is pushed to `data` by using [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/)

**Stage1**

```
{
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      "newestWineYear": {
        $max: "$year"
      },
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
}
```

2. The output of the first stage contains the entire documents in an  array which we had named as`data` and the `newestWineYear`

So, inorder to flatten the `data` array [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) is used.

**Stage2**

```
 {
    $unwind: "$data"
 }
```

3. Get the count of the wines that has been produced in the last 5 years.

I have used $group to get the count, and count is obtained using $sum.

Stage3

```
{
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      count: {
        "$sum": {
          $cond: [
            {
              "$gte": [
                "$data.year",
                {
                  "$subtract": [
                    "$newestWineYear",
                    5
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
}
```

A condition is added to [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to count only the wines that has been produced in the last 5 years.

Condition is available inside [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/).

It says:

```
 If "data.year" >= [ "$newestWineYear" - 5 ], then add 1 to count, else add 0
```

`data.year` is used because we had pushed year of the wines to the `data` array in our first stage of aggregation pipeline.

Final aggregation query can be found here: [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lrl7ILx7yWv)

Alternative method can be found [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pCzkhYKT3fc) without a $cond inside $group but a $match stage is introduced to get only the wines that has been produced in the last 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

As you guessed, you need to use mongo's aggregation framework.

Start with a simple pipeline with 3 simple steps:

1. group with $ group to get last year's data (returns an array)
2. remove array and get single documents ($ unwind operator)
3. filter documents with the $ match operator

Finally, you can replace the root of your documents to have better formed results.

Imagine having data like this:

```
[
  {
    "wine": "Red xxx",
    "year": 2018
  },
  {
    "wine": "Red yyy",
    "year": 2017
  },
  {
    "wine": "Red zzz",
    "year": 2017
  },
  {
    "wine": "White 1",
    "year": 2016
  },
  {
    "wine": "White 2",
    "year": 2013
  },
  {
    "wine": "White 3",
    "year": 2017
  },
  {
    "wine": "White 4",
    "year": 2009
  }
]
```

Here's the pipeline and [here you can see the results in playground.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nswDDL1PHxV)

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $group: {
    _id: null,
    "lastYear": {
      $max: "$year"
    },
    data: {
      $push: "$$ROOT"
    }
  }
},
{
  $unwind: "$data"
},
{
  $match: {
    $expr: {
      $gte: [
        "$data.year",
        {
          "$subtract": [
            "$lastYear",
            5
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
},
{
  "$replaceWith": "$data"
})
```